# Did Guenhwyvar undergo a sex change?

Tags: female-characters, forgotten-realms, legend-of-drizzt

If memory serves, Drizzt's panther companion Guenhwyvar was referred to as a 'him' in the early *Forgotten Realms* books (*Icewind Dale* and *Dark Elf* trilogies) but a 'her' in later works (such as *Starless Nights*, *Siege of Darkness* and so on). Was this deliberately rewritten, or is my memory just faulty?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### No: "he" was a publisher's error.

Quoting from [here](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Guenhwyvar) (emphasis mine):

> In [*The Collected Stories: The Legend of Drizzt Anthology*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Collected-Stories-Legend-Drizzt-Forgotten-ebook/dp/B005GLS7SU), R.A. Salvatore explained that while writing The Crystal Shard, he was told by TSR that magical items could not have a gender, despite his arguments otherwise. To his "horror," he later discovered after the book was published that **some of the more awkward uses of "it" were changed — presumably by a copyeditor — to the male pronoun**. Salvatore has subsequently responded to hundreds of letters from fans explaining this. Despite these publishing errors, Salvatore explained that **Guenhwyvar had always been a "she."**